# How to find the row number in a matching list

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I have two list that are not the same length. List (df1) does not have any row number but List df2 does. Im having trouble finding a match in any columns in df1 that match any columns in df2 and return the row number. For example, here is my two list below

```
df1 = [[2,4,6,8,9,10],[10,13,15,17,26,44],[27,28,34,37,40]]

df2 = [[120,1,2,4,5,6,8],[20,5,6,20,22,23,34],[132,8,12,13,34,45,46],[56,9,10,14,29,32,33],[29,1,22,13,23,33,35],[167,1,6,7,8,9,10],[15,0,2,3,5,6,8]]
```

I would like my result like this

```
result = [[[120,120,120,120],[20,],[132],[56],[56],[167,167,167,167,],[15,15,15]],[[132],[56],[29],[167]],[[20],[132]]]
```

Comment: Typo. Fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result as shown in the question doesn't appear to fit the description. Perhaps it should be:

```
df1 = [
    [2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10],
    [10, 13, 15, 17, 26, 44],
    [27, 28, 34, 37, 40]
]

df2 = [
    [120, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8],
    [20, 5, 6, 20, 22, 23, 34],
    [132, 8, 12, 13, 34, 45, 46],
    [56, 9, 10, 14, 29, 32, 33],
    [29, 1, 22, 13, 23, 33, 35],
    [167, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    [15, 0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8]
]

result = []

m = {n[0]: set(n[1:]) for n in df2}

for _df1 in df1:
    d = {}
    for x in _df1:
        for k, v in m.items():
            if x in v:
                d.setdefault(k, []).append(k)
    result.append([v for v in d.values()])

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[[[120, 120, 120, 120], [15, 15, 15], [20], [167, 167, 167, 167], [132], [56, 56]], [[56], [167], [132], [29]], [[20], [132]]]
```

Comment: Works Great. Appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

With your example:

```
df1 = [[2,4,6,8,9,10],[10,13,15,17,26,44],[27,28,34,37,40]] 
df2 = [[120,1,2,4,5,6,8],[20,5,6,20,22,23,34],[132,8,12,13,34,45,46],[56,9,10,14,29,32,33],[29,1,22,13,23,33,35],[167,1,6,7,8,9,10],[15,0,2,3,5,6,8]]
```

You can do like this:

```
result = []
for sublist1 in df1:
    row_numbers = []
    for i, sublist2 in enumerate(df2):
        if any(x in sublist2 for x in sublist1):
            row_numbers.append(i)
    result.append([df2[i] for i in row_numbers])

print(result)
```

Result will be like:

```
[[[120, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8], [120, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8], [120, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8], [120, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8]],
  [[132, 8, 12, 13, 34, 45, 46], [56, 9, 10, 14, 29, 32, 33], [29, 1, 22, 13, 23, 33, 35], [167, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]],
  [[20, 5, 6, 20, 22, 23, 34], [132, 8, 12, 13, 34, 45, 46]]]
```

Comment: Works. Is there any way to return only the row numbers. If not, I'm satisfied with this result. Thanks